# jquery insert special html code using .text()

Tags: jquery

Is there any ways inserting special html codes:

```
(&nbsp; &ensp; &emsp; &ndash; &mdash;)
```

using .text()?

Following construction will not work:

```
$.text('&nbsp');
```

JSFiddle (if necessary): http://jsfiddle.net/7yR95/

Comment: `text()` sets the text content of the element, so no. Why not use `html()` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use html() instead of text(), theres no way text() can make — to be a dash

check the fiddle for html()

```
$('.result').html('&mdash;');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yR95/1/

Comment: @Se0ng11- This is wrong answer OP wants answer using `text()`

Comment: @AmitAgrawal We cant insert that special character using text(), you should know what is diff b/w text() and html() in jquery

Comment: @Bala I know difference. You can also achieve using `append` but the question is - Can achieve using `text`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `'\xa0'` for `&nbsp;`:

```
.text('\xa0');
```

---

```
&nbsp;  ----> xa0

&ndash; ----> x96

&mdash; ----> x97
```

[see more in ascii table](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-ascii.htm)